# Document possible values for swagger/go swag while declaring the type as json.RawMessage

Tags: go

I have an endpoint that accepts something like

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Id  *uuid.UUID
    Payload  map[string]json.RawMessage
}
```

This is because I struggle with other ways to express multiple options in Go: The key determines the structure of the value. Imagine

```golang
type Bla {
    MeaningOfLife int
}
```

and

```golang
type Fasel {
    Quest string
    FavoriteColor string
}
```

which both would be a valid payload, behind a defined/guarding key. How can I convince swaggo to understand that there's two concrete valid values for the map values?